# materialize tabs! How to rename the tabs generated dinamically with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I have a small problem that I hope you can help me. I am using the element called "tabs" (tabs) of materializecss framework, but I am configuring it with javascript to allow the user to do certain things, such as: 
1. Add a new Tab. 
2.Edit the name of any tab (existing or those that are added).

I will show below the code that I already have:

```js
$("#Tab1").dblclick(function () {
                var texto = $("#Tab1").text();
        $("#Tab1").remove();
        $("#inputTab1").attr("type", "text");
        $("#inputTab1").val(texto);
        $("#inputTab1").focus();
});

$('#inputTab1').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
            
        var input1 = $(this).val();
        
        $("#inputTab1").before('<a class="active" id="Tab1" href="#test1">' + input1 +  '</a>');
        
        $("#inputTab1").val("");
        
        $("#inputTab1").attr("type", "hidden");
        
        
        $("#Tab1").dblclick(function () {
        
          var texto = $("#Tab1").text();
          $("#Tab1").remove();
          $("#inputTab1").attr("type", "text");
          $("#inputTab1").val(texto);
          $("#inputTab1").focus();
        });
    }
});


function addNew(){
    $(".pestanas").each(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
  $(".contenidos").each(function(){
      $(this).removeClass('active').css('display','none');
    
  })
  var id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
  var pesta = '<li class="tab col s3"><a class="pestanas active" id="Tab'+id+'" href="#test'+id+'">New Tab<input type="hidden" name="tab2" value="New Tab" /></a></li>';
  var conte = '<div id="test'+id+'" class="col s12 contenidos active">Text New Tab '+id+'</div>';
  $("#tabControl").before(pesta);
  $("#tabs").after(conte);
  $('ul.tabs').tabs();
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12" id="tabs">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab col s3" id="first"><a class="pestanas active" id="Tab1" href="#test1">name</a><input style="text-align: center; color: pink;" type="hidden" name="tab1" id ="inputTab1" value="" placeholder="new name"/></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a id="Tab2" href="#test2">New Tab<input type="hidden" name="tab2" value="New Tab" /></a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3" id="tabControl"><a id="control" onClick="addNew()" href="javascript:void(0)">+</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="test1" class="col s12">
      text first tab</div>
    <div id="test2" class="col s12">text second tab</div>
  </div>
```

The previous code does the following:
1. Add a new tab by clicking on the "+" button.
2. It allows to edit the name of the first tab when double clicking on the current name...

Well, What I would like is that when user adds a new tab, he can edit the name of the new tab too, not only the first tab but all tabs that the user added... I have tried of doing it and until now I have not had good results because it creates conflicts with the first tab.
In what way could I do this? Any script that you can provide to me? ... The idea is that each new tab that is added can also be edited doing doble click on the tab (example: the first tab). 
I would be very grateful if you could help me with this, it has had me crazy these days.

Comment: Try not to work with `id`'s too much when it comes to dynamically generating content. Use something like `$(document).on('dblclick', '.tab', function() {});` instead of `$('#Tab1').dblclick(function(){});`. This will help you to add those eventlisteners to newly generated objects. Hope this helped you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Basically, you need to extract your logic to apply events KeyUp and dblCkick for the new tabs.**

```js
var applyDblEvent = function (identifier) {
        $("#Tab" + identifier).dblclick(function () {
            var $Tab = $("#Tab" + identifier);
            var texto = $Tab.text();
            $Tab.remove();
            var $inputTab = $("#inputTab" + identifier);
            $inputTab.attr("type", "text");
            $inputTab.val(texto);
            $inputTab.focus();
        });
    };

    var applyKeyUpEvent = function (identifier) {
        $('#inputTab' + identifier).on('keyup', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode === 13) {
                var input = $(this).val();
                var $inputTab = $("#inputTab" + identifier);
                $inputTab.before('<a class="active" id="Tab' + identifier + '" href="#test' + identifier + '">' + input + '</a>');
                $inputTab.val("");
                $inputTab.attr("type", "hidden");

                applyDblEvent(identifier);
            }
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        applyDblEvent(1);
        applyKeyUpEvent(1);
    });

    function addNew() {
        $(".pestanas").each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
        $(".contenidos").each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active').css('display', 'none');
        });

        var id = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1);
        var pesta = '<li class="tab col s3"><a class="pestanas active" id="Tab' + id + '" href="#test' + id + '">New Tab</a><input style="text-align: center; color: pink;" type="hidden" name="tab' + id + '" id="inputTab' + id + '" value="New Tab" /></li>';
        var conte = '<div id="test' + id + '" class="col s12 contenidos active">Text New Tab ' + id + '</div>';

        $("#tabControl").before(pesta);
        $("#tabs").after(conte);
        $('ul.tabs').tabs();

        setTimeout(function() {
            $('ul.tabs').tabs('select_tab', 'test' + id);
        }, 100);

        applyDblEvent(id);
        applyKeyUpEvent(id);
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12" id="tabs">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab col s3" id="first"><a class="pestanas active" id="Tab1" href="#test1">name</a><input style="text-align: center; color: pink;" type="hidden" name="tab1" id ="inputTab1" value="" placeholder="new name"/></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a id="Tab2" href="#test2">New Tab<input type="hidden" name="tab2" value="New Tab" /></a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3" id="tabControl"><a id="control" onClick="addNew()" href="javascript:void(0)">+</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="test1" class="col s12">
      text first tab</div>
    <div id="test2" class="col s12">text second tab</div>
  </div>
```

**Hope this helps!**

Comment: it's almost working well, because if I click on the tab "+" it creates a new tab(that's fine, it's good) and it should jump to the div container of the created tab; however, it remains in the div of the tab "+", that should not do it. The idea is that when a new tab is created, it will immediately be placed on that tab that has been created. You got me? Could you help me please? I have tried to fix it but It doesn't work...

Comment: **You could execute something like this:** $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active", indexLastCreatedTab);

Comment: I updated the answer.  That was the only way `setTimeout` I could to provide the behavior you need.

Comment: Executing the code here in SO is working.  I'm with no alternatives :-)

Comment: yeah you're totally right. It's working now, I was using the code wrong, I did realize and I did fix it, now it's working. Really thank you so so much! You have saved my life jajaja Thank you for your help.